# return value from listener

Tags: java, android

I have static method which plays music. How to return value from this method when play completed?

```
public static int playSample(Context context, int resid) {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);

    try {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // from here i want return some value that play is completed
            }
        });
        afd.close();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e("a", "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("a", "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("a", "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just pass a `OnCompletionListener` to the static function as a 'callback'?

```
public static int playSample(Context context, int resid, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener callback) {
    //...
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(callback);
}
```

Then use the function like this:

```
StaticActivity.playSample(this, R.id.random, new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // do something when playing completes
    }
}
```

If you don't care about a callback in all cases, you can probably just supply `null` and only set the OnCompletionListener on the MediaPlayer object if it's not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MediaListener implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletedListener{

    public static final int PLAY_COMPLETED = 12345

    public MediaListener(){}
    public int Indicator = 0 

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Indicator = PLAY_COMPLETED
    }
}

...
MediaListener ml = new MediaListener();
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(ml);
//check ml.Indicator
```

its not a good coding style but if you H A V E to return the result there, you can busyWait like this:

```
while(ml.Inidcator != PLAY_COMPLETED){
    sleep(50) //
}
```

That means if your static method gets called from the UI Thread it will block anything till play is completed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good way by return a value, The **onCompletion** method is called asynchronously, You can do the thing you want such as playing the next music in this method instead of by the return value.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the value returned? In the on completion listener, place code to call an external method. Have this external method process the 'return' value